# App contains content that doesn't comply with the Inappropriate Ads policy. (Google Play)

Tags: google-play, admob, ads

My App is already teen. What should I do now in order to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So "Content ratings" give you 12+, but in "Target audience and content" what have you set? If you have set also <12, is the problem.

Comment: @FreeLearning It's 12+

Comment: You can try going to AdMob, Blocking Controls, Ad Content Rating, Set to Teen.
Then you can try resubmitting the app.

Comment: @FreeLearning It works!